# Dell Poweredge 860 with CentOS eth0 link is down. Trying to configure a static IP

Tags: centos, dell-poweredge, broadcom

I decided to recycle an old server, [Dell Poweredge 860 Service Tag: B21N5F1](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/servicetag/B21N5F1/drivers?s=BSD), that had vyatta (a what use to be open-source firewall os) firewall installed on it. I went ahead and did a clean install of CentOS 6.6 (64 bit) via a bootable usb. I have installed CentOS 6.6 atleast eight times before this, on other machines, and the install has always been smooth as butter. Not this time though.
I have followed the following documentation to a tee.

https://github.com/rharmonson/richtech/wiki/CentOS-6.5-Minimal-x86_64-Base-Installation-Guide

I have configured the server with a static IP, specified the nameservers, specified the gateway, and tried three different ethernet cables.

yet...

I cannot ping my gateway or 8.8.8.8

I came across Bug 486601, but I'm skeptical because this looks like a bug that has to do with DHCP. I'll have to try adding LINKDELAY=60 to the ifcfg-eth0 file and see what happens.

But PLEASE!

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated!

> ```
> nano /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
>
> DEVICE=eth0
> HWADDR=00:14:16:3B:8E:AB
> TYPE=Ethernet
> UUID=I dont feel like typing this
> ONBOOT=yes
> NM_CONTROLLED=no
> BOOTPROTO=none
> IPADDR=192.168.32.35
> NETMASK=255.255.255.0
>
>
> nano /etc/sysconfig/network
>
> NETWORKING=yes
> HOSTNAME=server2.mydomain.com
> GATEWAY=192.168.32.2
>
>
> route -n
> Kernel IP routing table
> Destination     Gateway Genmask       Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
> 192.168.32.0  0.0.0.0   255.255.255.0 U     0      0      0 eth0
> 169.254.0.0   0.0.0.0   255.255.0.0    U     1002   0      0 eth0
>  0.0.0.0      192.168.32.2   0.0.0.0 UG     0      0      0 eth0
>
>
>  nano /etc/resolv.conf
>  nameserver 8.8.8.8
>  nameserver 8.8.4.4
>
>  ifconfig
>  eth0    Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:14:16:3B:8E:AB
>             inet addr: 192.168.32.35 Bcast: 192.168.32.255 Mask: 255.255.255.0
>             UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric: 1
>             RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>             RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes: 0 (0.0 b)
>             Interrupt:16 Memory:fe9e0000-fea00000
>
> lo         Link encap:Local Loopback
>             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>             inet6 addr:  ::1/128 Scope:Host
>             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
>             RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>             RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes: 0 (0.0 b)
>
> mii-tool eth0
> eth0: no link
> ```

Comment: Plug in an Ethernet cable.

Comment: Do you have a link light on the NIC and the switch port it's connected to? If so, maybe try overriding auto-negotiation, something like `ETHTOOL_OPTS="autoneg off speed 100 duplex full"`

Comment: Does it work if you use DHCP instead of a static address?

Answer (score 0):

Success!

I was able to access the NIC configuration settings during my the PE860's boot process via

> ```
>  Ctrl and S.
> ```

Once there, I changed the NIC configuration from

> ```
>  Autonegotiate to 100Mb Full.
> ```

Then I let the server finish booting.

Put in the root password.

Invoked the interface via the command

> ```
>  ifup eth0.
> ```

Finally I issued the command

> ```
> yum update
> ```

Thank you for your thought provoking suggestions.

Michael Hampton you sure put the **Ham** in Hampton. You joker you. ;)